# Error al crear una api

Tags: django, postman, webapi

Buenas estoy aprendiendo a crear apis con django y uso postman para poder visualizar la información pero al usar el método post o cualquier otro que no sea get me sale lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo de la vista es el siguiente

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# Create your views here.
def simple(request):
    
return JsonResponse({"method": request.method})
```

se supone que deberia darme como resultado el método que este usando pero en vez de eso me sale un html a que se debe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo es un error 403, deberías enviar el `csrftoken` en el request, te dejo el enlace a la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax) de como hacer eso.

Si no quieres usar el `csrftoken` debes agregar este decorador `@csrf_exempt` a la vista:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
def simple(request):
    return JsonResponse({"method": request.method})
```

Comment: muchas gracias en donde estoy aprendiendo no explicaron eso ahora si ya funciona todo bien

Comment: Si la repuesta te ayudó y está correcta la deberías aceptar, saludos.